# Create a list of the given length in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, maxlength

How to create a list with a given length? I want my list to take only 3 variables, it should not expand.

How to do that in Dart / Flutter?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: This is a Q/A actually, I am preparing my answer at the moment, will be ready in a min.

Answer (score 7):

- Well, you can use List.filled() to make it happen. 
  This creates a list of the given length with [fill] at each position.
  The [length] must be a non-negative integer.

  ```
        final zeroList = List<int>.filled(3, 0, growable: true); // [0, 0, 0]
  ```

In this way you will have a list with given length, you can only put three variables inside that list, and default variables will be 0.

---

### Here is more detailed information which is quated from #dart-documentation.

The created list is fixed-length if [growable] is false (the default) and growable if [growable] is true. If the list is growable, increasing
its [length] will not initialize new entries with [fill]. After being created and filled, the list is no different from any other growable or fixed-length list created using [] or other [List] constructors.

- All elements of the created list share the same [fill] value.

  ```
    final shared = List.filled(3, []);
    shared[0].add(499);
    print(shared);
  ```
- You can use [List.generate] to create a list with a fixed length and a new object at each position.

  ```
    final unique = List.generate(3, (_) => []);
    unique[0].add(499);
    print(unique); // [[499], [], []]
  ```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `generate` like this:

```
List result = List.generate(3, (index) => index.toString());// [0,1,2]
```